# Chrome doesn't display URL gadgets in Google Sites

Tags: google-chrome, url, google-classic-sites, gadget

I own a Google Apps domain, and I've built a site in Google Sites. Within the site I've embedded some gadgets, added by URL.

The problem occurs when I open the site in Chrome: the gadgets aren't displayed and there's a white space instead of them. This doesn't happen when opening the site in Firefox.

Here's the difference. This is the page as displayed in Firefox:

[image: page with gadgets dispalyed]

This is the page from Google Chrome, instead (without the gadgets):

[image]

How can I prevent this behavior? I'm aware that the gadgets loaded by an external URL can be seen as non-secure items, but why is Chrome blocking them at all?

Comment: Have you checked this with the web inspector (Tools → Developer Tools)? Also, this happens when you are logged in or logged out of Google?

Comment: It happens in both cases: I loaded the site in an incognito wondow and the problem remains.

What should I chek with the web inspector?

Comment: Do you have some privacy extensions installed on Chrome? Looks like a Twitter gadget, right? If you have any privacy extension installed, it might be the culprit. Have you checked the site from different machines?

Comment: Same problem on a different machine with the newest version of chrome. The fact is: in older versions of chrome, those items were recognized as non secure, and a pop-up asked if I wanted to load them, or not. Now there's no warning and they are not loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to the new security rules adopted in Chrome 21.
URLs in the source code must use HTTPS instead of HTTP, as stated [here](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/sites/ILVsJCHhFDc/_HeZUVKqUSsJ).